# how to feed different data formats when training a multi-input Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I'm experimenting with building a multi-input Keras model for classifying medical images. The multi-input will include (i) raw image to be passed through a CNN, and (ii) traditional computer vision features included as an auxiliary input. These are then concatenated and used an input to a small neural network of dense layers. Please the image below for description of model architecture:

[multi-input model architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwcPp.png)

The problem is that I cannot train the model with `model.fit` since I have a large image dataset (over a million) and this would not fit in memory. Therefore I need to use `model.fit_generator`, which gives me access to the `flow_from_directory` call which will read the images from directory. However, now the issue is that the auxiliary input (manual computer vision features, which is just a vector of 11 features per image) can not be fed in via `model.fit_generator`.

How can I train this custom network?

Please let me know if my question needs to be more specific or requires more information.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a concatenation layer in the middle of your multi input model. See section [7.1.2 of Deep Learning with Python](https://github.com/ClaudeCoulombe/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/7.1-Keras_functional_API.ipynb)

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras import layers
from keras import Input

text_vocabulary_size = 10000
question_vocabulary_size = 10000
answer_vocabulary_size = 500

# The text input is a variable-length sequence of integers. 
# Note that you can optionally name the inputs.
text_input = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='text')
# Embeds the inputs into a sequence of vectors of size 64
# embedded_text = layers.Embedding(64, text_vocabulary_size)(text_input)
# embedded_text = layers.Embedding(output_dim=64, input_dim=text_vocabulary_size)(text_input)
embedded_text = layers.Embedding(text_vocabulary_size,64)(text_input)
# Encodes the vectors in a single vector via an LSTM
encoded_text = layers.LSTM(32)(embedded_text)
# Same process (with different layer instances) for the question
question_input = Input(shape=(None,),dtype='int32',name='question')
# embedded_question = layers.Embedding(32, question_vocabulary_size)(question_input)
# embedded_question = layers.Embedding(output_dim=32, input_dim=question_vocabulary_size)(question_input)
embedded_question = layers.Embedding(question_vocabulary_size,32)(question_input)
encoded_question = layers.LSTM(16)(embedded_question) 
# Concatenates the encoded question and encoded text
concatenated = layers.concatenate([encoded_text, encoded_question],axis=-1)
# Adds a softmax classifier on top
answer = layers.Dense(answer_vocabulary_size, activation='softmax')(concatenated)
# At model instantiation, you specify the two inputs and the output.
model = Model([text_input, question_input], answer)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
```